# PHP curl tls 1.2

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm using

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```

And my curl_version() says:

```
{
  "version_number": 473600,
  "age": 4,
  "features": 4179869,
  "ssl_version_number": 0,
  "version": "7.58.0",
  "host": "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu",
  "ssl_version": "OpenSSL/1.1.1",
  "libz_version": "1.2.11",
  "protocols": [
    "dict",
    "file",
    "ftp",
    "ftps",
    "gopher",
    "http",
    "https",
    "imap",
    "imaps",
    "ldap",
    "ldaps",
    "pop3",
    "pop3s",
    "rtmp",
    "rtsp",
    "smb",
    "smbs",
    "smtp",
    "smtps",
    "telnet",
    "tftp"
  ]
}
```

Am I on the correct TLS 1.2 version?

It's just that this version "OpenSSL/1.1.1" confuses me a little

Comment: OpenSSL is a toolkit with its separate version number. To confuse you even more: The OpenSSL 1.1.1 ssl library implements the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL v2/v3) and Transport Layer Security (TLS v1) protocols. I would use the constant `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2` instead of `6`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware first of all, thanks! But, I changed it to "CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2" and the curl_version() keep returns the same numbers

Comment: Yes, of course, the constant is equivalent to the number six. There's nothing wrong with the numbers you see, you should be able to use TLS 1.2.